# Parsing out things surrounded by quotes in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to make a parser that would only take text surrounded by quotes and place it in a new file I've already tried many times but can't figure it out it would have to take the original text out of a file by the way then place it in a new file I would like to do this in C++.

---

This is what I currently have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char current_letter;
    char quote_mark = '"';
    int isquote = 0;

    std::cin >> current_letter;

    LOOP : do
{
    if(current_letter == quote_mark) {++isquote;}
        if(isquote == 1 && current_letter != quote_mark) {std::cout << current_letter;}
        if(isquote == 1 && current_letter == quote_mark) {--isquote;}
        if(isquote == 0) {goto LOOP;}
} while (cin >> current_letter);

if(cin != current_letter) {cout << "END" <<endl;}

return(0);
```

It doesn't print anything now but it used to print out random stuff or just quote marks.

Comment: post what you have written and what problem you are facing?

Comment: I posted the code below in the answers section I'd move it to this top part but I'm not at my laptop now

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
string currStr = "";

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
  if (str[i] != '\"') currStr += str[i];
}

cout << currStr << "\n";
```

<s>This won't work if there are double quotes within the text that you want to parse however.</s>